React to track changes on a custom object
I understand that react wants to track changes and that it has a built-in mechanism for tracking those via states but I don't understand why it would be impossible to integrate an instance of a custom class and use that for state management in one of my components.
Consider these two components:
import ArrayManager from "./arr.js";
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const MemoryContext = createContext(null);

const MyComponent = () => {
  const memory = useContext(MemoryContext);

  const handleClick = () => memory.push({type: 'system', value: 'Hello World'});

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button>
      <ul>
        { memory.map((a, i) => <li key={i}>{a.value}</li>) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [arrayManager] = useState(new ArrayManager([{type: 'system', value: 'Hello World'}]));

  return (
    <MemoryContext.Provider value={arrayManager}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MemoryContext.Provider>
  );
}

ArrayManager is nothing more than a wrapper around Array class:
class ArrayManager extends Array {
  constructor(initialArray = []) {
    super();

    if (Array.isArray(initialArray)) this.push(...initialArray);
  }

  push(...el) {
    console.log('Pushing ' + JSON.stringify(el));
    super.push(...el);
  }
};

export default ArrayManager;

When you click on that "Click Me" button you'll observe that nothing visually happens. React won't detect changes to state, thus won't be able to re-render the component. I understand that. How would I go about creating such structures though? I guess I am breaking the whole idea of react with what I am trying to do, and there is actually a better way to do stuff like this.
I also found this: https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore#subscribing-to-an-external-store But I couldn't integrate that properly in my example, I still observed the same result as on the code above.

In React, useState is hardwired to the rendering mechanism. If you change a state value (by calling the set-function) then the component that "owns" the state variable will re-render, allowing the new state value to be displayed. I can't see why you would want to rebuild or circumvent that very convenient mechanism.

I am having an issue where state is tightly tied up to the output while also being heavily modified. I have to perform many editing operations both pushes and alterations in for single render depending on different conditions. Ofc, I could still do that with state by mutating it through callback with prev, but it becomes messy from what it looks like. Custom object would allow me a lot of flexibility of what I could do to the structure of the array. I understand that is probably not the react way but I am struggling to understand how to resolve my issue in a react way but also nicely.

the provider value should return available methods and values that things within the provider can access. In your example you have not done that. Probably read through the implementation documentation for this design pattern. For classes https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html for hooks https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext. when subscribing to an external store you still need to bring the updates back into reacts state management

You could make a temporary object this.tmpData = { ... theData } and modify that as needed. When done, pass that object to the set-function: setTheData(this.tmpData). Of course this would only work if no calls in between are done to setData() from other sources.
